# truffle log location?

Tags: private-blockchain, truffle, migration

Does anyone know where truffle keeps logs?

I am unable to perform a migration.  It gives me no error message; it just hangs on:

```
Running migration: 1_initial_migration.js
  Deploying Migrations...
```

Yes, I have the account unlocked.  Yes, that account has lots of ether.

Comment: Can you provide with what command configuration are you running geth. Truffle uses a default port which is 8545 is your RPC running on the same one. Also you can use the --verbose-rpc parameter and set it to true in truffle config or at command line so that you can see the log details.

Comment: (I'm running on port 8545.)  Yes I've tried --verbose-rpc but it is not a log in the traditional sense.  I want a report of what is or is not happening, not a real-time glimpse of the conversation.  When I run that flag, my console is filled with... I don't even know what the hell it is.  I could print it out but it's besides the point.  What I want from truffle is a meaningful error message.  Do you know how I can get that?